# javascript event onkeypress event won't run

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to alert the user whenever he/she presses enter. I decided to use javascript for this. I have the following bit of html:

```
   <div id="all">
           <h1>Welcome to the awesome chat system.</h1>
           <input type="text" id="name"><br/>
           <textarea  rows='30' id="chatArea" disabled='true'>
           </textarea>
           <textarea id="writtenThing" onkeypress="keyfunction(e)"></textarea>
           <button id="send">Send</button>
    </div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
       <script>
            function keyfunction(e)
            {

                if(e.keyCode == 13)
                {
                    alert("things to do...");
                }

            }

       </script>
```

However the problem that I'm facing is that even though I press enter inside the textarea my browser does not alert me. I'm sure I'm using a browser which supports this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the event to the function:

```
   <textarea id="writtenThing" onkeyup="keyfunction(event)"></textarea>
```

Add some cross browser support:

```
        function keyfunction(e)
        {
            if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13)
            {
                alert("things to do...");
            }
        }
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3MF3h/

Answer (score 1):

Use the following javscript.

```
 document.getElementById("writtenThing").onkeypress = function (e) 
 {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
  {
     alert("things to do...");
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace onkeypress with onkeyup/onkeydown

Also, correct the code with following:

onkeypress="keyfunction(event)"

Comment: I chaged it however it does not alert

Comment: you are passing "e" in the function...instead, pass "event"

Comment: onkeypress="keyfunction(event)"